# How to grab a text value from second quotation in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a formula to grab all text within a string of text /sentence of the SECOND quotation field. For example, I have the following text"

```
B2: "Description":"BLUE CAR"
C2: "Description":"RED CAR"
D2: "Description":"PINK CAR"
```

I found a formula that can grab the second string in quotes which is:
BLUE CAR
RED CAR
PINK CAR

```
=MID(B2,FIND("""",B2)+1,FIND("""",B2,FIND("""",B2)+1)-FIND("""",B2)-1)
```

But this gives me:

```
Description
Description
Description
```

Is there a way to grab the second quotation string?

[image]

Comment: Maybe look for `:"` instead of just a quotation mark

Comment: Context is important, your values aren't as you originally described.

Comment: Try this: `= CHOOSECOLS( TEXTSPLIT( B2, CHAR(34) ), 4 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your value was in **A1** ...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,":"), 1, 3), """", ""), ",", "")
```

... however, will depend on your version of Excel.

It also assumes that there are no additional commas in the string apart from the last one.  You can fix that though if need be.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try using `TEXTAFTER()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(B2,":"),"""",)
```

---

Edit:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(B2,","),": ",2),"""",)
```

---

Using `MAP()`

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=MAP(B2:B4,LAMBDA(m,SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(m,","),": ",2),"""",)))
```

---

Note: Formulas will work with `MS365` current channel and the last two edits are based on OP's edits.

---

Answer (score 0):

Here another one with basic approach..

=MID(A1:A3,FIND(""":""",A1:A3)+3,LEN(A1:A3)-(FIND(""":""",A1:A3)+3))

[image]